# In AT&T assembly, what's difference between =2 and =$2?

Tags: linux, assembly, x86, constants, att

I used to think when using a integer as a constant, I always need to append a "$" sign, unless the number is interpreted as an address, so I had:

```
.data
a=$2
.equ b,3
.text
.globl _start
_start:
movl $a,%ebx
movl $b,%ecx
movl $1,%eax
int $0x80
```

This code is compiled into:

```
0:  bb 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%ebx
5:  b9 03 00 00 00          mov    $0x3,%ecx
a:  b8 01 00 00 00          mov    $0x1,%eax
f:  cd 80                   int    $0x80
```

I don't know how as compiler deal with a=$2, why $2 is compiled into 0x0?
Then I removed "$",

```
.data
a=2
.equ b,3
.text
.globl _start
_start:
movl $a,%ebx
movl $b,%ecx
movl $1,%eax
int $0x80
```

This time, the compiled code is correct:

```
0:  bb 02 00 00 00          mov    $0x2,%ebx
5:  b9 03 00 00 00          mov    $0x3,%ecx
a:  b8 01 00 00 00          mov    $0x1,%eax
f:  cd 80                   int    $0x80
```

So my question is, what's the difference between '2' and '$2' here?

Comment: I assume that output you are showing is an `objdump` of a `.o` file and not of a final executable. Because `a=$2` and then later `movl $a,%ebx` would be resolved by the assembler to `movl $$2,%ebx` . That would move the address of the label `$2` to _EBX_. Unless you defined a symbol `$2` in one of the objects you link I'd expect you would get an undefined reference when you attempt to link to an executable.

Comment: If you are dealing with object files (`.o`) when using _OBJDUMP_ then the 0x0 you see is a placeholder for the linker to resolve at link time. If you were to do `objdump -Dr myfile.o` it will likely show a relocation entry. for the symbol `$2` . Something like `1: R_386_32     $2` . When the linker finally creates an executable that 0x00 will be filled in by the address of the label `$2`

Comment: Michael Petch is to the point!